# Run CUDA SASS instructions

Tags: cuda, gpu, disassembly

I am new to this world. So I have question related to compiling a CUDA file.

For a particular reason (not explaining here), I need to follow this path,

1) Transform CUDA source code to sass file

2) edit the sass file

3) run the code

I know how to do 1, `nvcc -cubin sourcecode.cu`, this generates `sourcecode.cubin` and then do, `cuobjdump --dump-sass sourcecode.cubin` . But this one looses the host code. So is there any way I can go to SASS and then somehow run the sass file?

Comment: No you can't do this

Comment: @talonmies. explanations would be welcomed. Question is interesting and deserves more than this comment

Comment: @RegisPortalez: I'm sure this question is a duplicate, which is why I have not answered. I just haven't found the duplicate yet

Comment: There are no methods using the nvidia toolchain to do this.  If you want to use 3rd party toolchains, then the [maxas](https://github.com/NervanaSystems/maxas) assembler may be of interest.  If you search for maxas and sass you will find questions here on the cuda tag that in my opinion are a duplicate of this question.